# Python text.replace for removing section of a string

Tags: python, string, text, replace

I would like to see how I could remove a certain section of a string without leaving the blank space.

When running this code it outputs `nice    today`, the problem is that I am replacing the characters with a blank space. Is there a fix to this or should I be using a completely different method entirely?

```
text = ("hello bye there ")

print(text.replace("hello", "nice").replace("there","today").replace("bye", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove white space at first:

```
text = ("hello bye there ")
print(text.replace("hello", "nice").replace("there","today").replace(" ", '').replace("bye" , " "))
```

the output will be:

```
nice today
```